# How to add Search button in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a simple app which is accessing mobile contact list and displaying in `ul`.Now as per my requirement i have to add a search button at the right of the header ie. at `Contact Directory` and which should be like on clicking that search button a search field should get opened from where one can enter the Names and `ul` should get refreshed as per that but i am not able to do it..Here is the HTML page that i am using..

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="c">

<div id="header" class="header" data-filter="true">
    <h1>Contact Directory</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
<ul id="ContactList"></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle link..[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et2nLwfb/12)

Also one  more thing i have to show the contact list in `ul` only because my java script code is populating that dynamically ..
Please help me ..Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data-filter="true" with autocomplete in jquery mobile

**CSS**

```
.ui-input-search{display:none;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header" class="">
        <h3>Contact Directory</h3>
        <a href="" data-role="none" id="btn_search" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right">Search</a>
    </div>

    <div role="main" id="listadoListas" class="ui-content">
        <form class="ui-filterable" id="">
            <input id="autocomplete-input" data-type="search" placeholder="Search...">
        </form>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-input="#autocomplete-input" id="ContactList">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn_search", function(){
   $(".ui-input-search").toggle();
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/et2nLwfb/30/)**

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="#searchPage" data-role="button" data-icon="search">Search</a>
```

check demo here
http://jsfiddle.net/et2nLwfb/25/

Comment: if your javascript create ul dynamically then its easy to handle .. can you please upload your code in jsfiddle . let me help you there

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/et2nLwfb/12/ This is the fiddle link and i want to add the search button in the top header ie. contact directory and it should search the data

Comment: I am sorry to tell you but it is not working on the way i was expecting and asked in the post ..Anyways ,..Thanks

Comment: Yes I think logic will remain same you just need to add new page for search result